# Why does this Ruby statement throw an exception? (Arrays/Bools)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, exception, cron

I'm not a Ruby guy, I just play one on television. I have to modify someone's old Cron job to pull down some JSON and convert it into objects.

Here's the code

```
raw_json = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("url removed to protect the innocent"))

tags = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_json)

puts tags.count
```

tags.count will accurately trace as 5, but THAT LINE immediately causes a crash as follows:

```
5 #the accurate count!
rake aborted!
undefined method `count' for false:FalseClass
```

What is the dealio?

Comment: An accurate array. But I figured out what is happening. The first request (this is being run on a loop), returns an accurate array, but the second loop returns nothing hence the False... how can I make sure that JSON.decode at least gives me an empty collection?

Comment: tags = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_json) || []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the contents of `raw_json`? What appears to be happening is that `ActiveSupport::JSON#decode` is returning false (hence `undefined method 'count' for false:FalseClass`). I think `JSON#decode` only returns false when given an empty string, which would mean `HTTP#get` is returning an empty string. Check on `raw_json` and see if it contains what you expect.

Comment: But it's not returning false because it's reporting an accurate collection count... how could "False" return 5? And raw_json is absolutely correct and has the content I am expecting.

Answer (score 1):

so I have no idea what is going on here, but JSON.decode *should* give you a hash, which doesn't have a count method. It does have a size method though

```
tags.size
```

if that doesn't work, try doing p tags, or puts tags.class.name to try and figure out what you are working with

Comment: actually tags.size and tags.count both return the correct number, 5, go figure.  puts tags.class.name prints out as "Array" - so there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently tags is false , which may mean that your Net::HTTP.get failed (I guess your URL is wrong).
Try to print tags to see what it is. (I guess anyway, that you should use a valid URI)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that:

```
>> ActiveSupport::JSON::decode("")
=> false
>> ActiveSupport::JSON::decode("false")
=> false
```

This is a very strange behavior.